# Classification of all simple $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$ modules. Why use $\mbox{Sym}?$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

In Fulton-Harris's book on Representation theory, it is stated that all finite-dimensional simple $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}$-modules of the form $V(\lambda), \lambda \in P^+,$ are isomorphic to a submodule of $\mbox{Sym}^{a_1}V\otimes \mbox{Sym}^{a_2}(\Lambda^{2}V)\otimes \cdots \otimes \mbox{Sym}^{a_n}(\Lambda^nV)$, where $V= \mathbb C^{n+1}, \lambda = \sum a_i\omega_i, a_i \in \mathbb Z_{\geq 0}$ and $\omega_i$ are the fundamental weights.

Although I understood the result, I can't find a good reason to use symmetric tensor power instead of the "regular" tensor power.  It is known that $V(\omega_k)\cong \Lambda^k V$. Denoting by $v\in \Lambda^k V$ any highest weight vector of weight $\omega_k$, we see that $v\otimes \cdots \otimes v  = v^{\otimes m}$ has weight $m\omega_k, m\in \mathbb Z_{\geq0}$. This way, It would sense to me to state that

$$V^{\otimes a_1}\otimes (\Lambda^2V)^{\otimes a_2} \otimes \cdots \otimes (\Lambda^n V)^{\otimes a_n}$$
contains a highest weight vector of weight  $a_1\omega_1+ \cdots+a_n\omega_n = \lambda$, and thus a submodule isomorphic to $V(\lambda)$.

Why does he use symmetric tensor power here instead of the construction I just made? Is it just preference?

Comment: I think one of the reasons could be that $sl_2$ irreps are of the form $Sym^kV$ where $V$ is the standard representation.

Comment: I think it is just a preference -- I guess the slight benefit is that the symmetric powers are smaller?  I think the tensor power version is more commonly used anyway. Either way though, the highest weight vector you found in the tensor power lives inside the symmetric power, so it's not really a different argument.

Comment: It is just preference: you could also find $V(\omega_k)$ inside $V^{\otimes k}$ in characteristic zero for example. What is nice about this construction is that it works in any characteristic to construct all the induced representations of the group $\operatorname{SL}_{n+1}$, and that it's closely connected to the construction of irreps via line bundles on the flag variety. You can find more about the flag variety story in the book _Young Tableaux_ by Fulton, and perhaps explains the preference towards this method of construction.